# QGIS Ubuntu 3.4 SQL Query Composer in WFS Connection Dialog

Tags: qgis, sql, wfs

The QGIS 3.4 documentation mentions the procedure of filtering the features of a WFS through the connection dialog box either by double-clicking on the layer of interest, or by clicking the "Build Query" button.  However, there is no example of query building in the resulting SQL Query Composer dialog box, and I see so way to build a query in the same fashion as you would through the "Filter" function from the Layers panel after adding the WFS to the map.  Specifically, I see no way of pulling in the field values to select from.  Which might be workable if you have used the particular layer before and made note of the columns and  all their values, but unless I'm missing something, it's not possible where you are using the WFS for the first time and don't know how the database is structured.  The clickable options seem to be geared more to spatial processing functions rather than selecting field values for filtering.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can't get the values of attributes from WFS without reading them but it is simple to check what attributes exists and of what datatype they are with DescribeFeatureType. Example: https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&TypeName=topp:states&request=DescribeFeatureType

Comment: As a user you can't ever know the structure of the underlying database that a WFS is using, you can just use/access the exposed feature types and attributes.

Comment: You can use a DescribeFeatureType request to know what you can query on.

Comment: I appreciate all the input and am still trying to reconcile the tutorial example, which was to filter the features using the Query Composer rather than filter from the map. So if I want to see the actual field values for that purpose would I then need to use GetFeature?